# How do I automate clicking a button in an application's window with AppleScript?

Tags: macos, applescript

Let's say I want to click a button that appears somewhere within a window, using AppleScript. `click button` works, but you have to know which button exactly you want to press.

---

**For example:** Scanning is a bit cumbersome when you always have to wait for the scanner to finish, then switch to Image Capture.app, then click *Scan* again.

So, I want to automate clicking this button here …

[image]

Well, I thought that would be relatively easy, but in the beginning this is as far as I got:

```
tell application "System Events"
    tell process "Image Capture"
        click button "Scan" of window "Image Capture"
    end tell
end tell
```

Of course, the button is buried deeper than that (i.e. in some Split Group).

With the [Accessibility Inspector](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#samplecode/UIElementInspector/Introduction/Intro.html) I can see where it is, but do I really have to go down the UI element tree to find the button? Is there any shortcut? If not, what am I missing in `click button "Scan" of window "Image Capture"`?

[image]

More general: **Where do I find a button in the UI element hierarchy?**

Comment: hey man, similar question here > http://superuser.com/q/1172526/234141, can you please help out?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If the button is not available directly, you might have to guess.

What works in High Sierra is:

```
tell application "System Events"
    tell process "Image Capture"
        click button "Scan" of group 2 of splitter group 1 of window "Image Capture"
    end tell
end tell
```

On older macOS releases, `group 1` may have to be used.

Another workaround would be to activate the window and press the space bar:

```
tell application "Image Capture"
    activate
    tell application "System Events" to key code 49
end tell
```

---

You can actually try to near it down by running commands like:

```
UI elements of window 1
UI elements of splitter group 1 of window 1
UI elements of group 1 of splitter group 1 of window 1
```

or, as @Lri said in the comments:

```
properties of UI elements of window 1
properties of UI elements of UI elements of window 1
```

This will present you with a list of elements contained, and you can guess your way from there.

Comment: [UI Browser](http://pfiddlesoft.com/uibrowser) also shows the integer indexes used by System Events, and can display all UI elements of an app in a column view. It's $55 though. ▪ A possibly faster way to narrow down elements manually: `properties of UI elements of UI elements of window 1`

Answer (score 1):

This has worked for me:

```
entire contents of window 1
```

when this came up short:

```
UI elements of window 1
```

Answer (score 1):

In MacOS High Sierra 10.13.6, and Image Capture 7.0, the above answer worked with this slight modification:

```
tell application "System Events"
    tell process "Image Capture"
        click button "Scan" of group 2 of splitter group 1 of window "Image Capture"
    end tell
end tell
```

Comment: Thanks, good to know. You could have also suggested an edit to my answer. I fixed my post.