# Identify Mac OS X Window, Group, and Text Field names for use in AppleScript

Tags: macos, applescript

I have an Applescript in which I wish to set the value of the text fields `Name` and `Password` of a window belonging to the process `SecurityAgent`.

It is similar to the following:

```
tell window "Authenticate" of process "SecurityAgent"
    tell group 1
        set value of text field 1 to "king"
        set value of text field 2 to "king1"
    end tell
    click button "OK" of group 2
end tell
```

While my script is also referring to the process `SecurityAgent`, the window in question is the one that pops up when you shut down OS X, and another user is logged in. The `SecurityAgent` window pops up asking for the administrator username and password in order to complete the shut down process. I do not know how to refer to the text fields in said window.

My question is, how do I find out the name of these text fields, the group they belong to, and the window they belong to? Is there a method of mapping OS X windows so I can refer to them in the AppleScript? I can't seem to find information concerning this anywhere.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I once [tried to click a button in the Image Capture application](https://superuser.com/q/336551/48078) and it took me a while to find this particular button. As explained in my question / answer there, there is a way, using the *UIElementInspector*. You can [download it for free from Apple](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#samplecode/UIElementInspector/Introduction/Intro.html) (download link is at the top in a button, direct link [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/samplecode/UIElementInspector/UIElementInspector.zip)).

It allows you to peek into the UI elements of each window you're hovering. Pressing <kbd>Cmd</kbd>-<kbd>F7</kbd> locks its contents to the element you're hovering.

[image]

The "fun" part is actually figuring out how the window is grouped, and which elements belong to which parent. The $55 application [UI Browser](http://pfiddlesoft.com/uibrowser/) claims to do a better job at this.

When you're manually debugging AppleScript, and you are in the scope of a window, you can try to guess your way down to individual elements using commands like:

```
UI elements of window 1
UI elements of splitter group 1 of window 1
UI elements of group 1 of splitter group 1 of window 1
```

These will give you a list that you can use to narrow down your search for elements and their respective titles.

Comment: +100 for letting me know about UIElementInspector

Comment: @slhck - Wow! What a fantastic answer. It is very much appreciated, and I will get to work right away on this. Curious however, as I'm new to AppleScript in general; How would I make the `UI elements` commands?

Comment: @Stef Well, for example `UI Elements of window "Authenticate" of process ...`. Just do this in AppleScript editor and look at the results at the bottom. I unfortunately haven't found a more efficient way to do this though.

Comment: @slhck - No no that sounds perfect. And ends up UI Browser offers a one month full feature trial, so I'll be able to give that a go as well. Again, thanks a bunch.

Comment: @stefmikhail Sure, no problem! Let me know how UI Browser works for you, haven't had the time yet to try it!

Comment: Had a chuckle when opening UIElementInspector to find it "cannot be opened because the developer cannot be verified." 