# Command line document scanner

Tags: macos, command-line, terminal, scanner

Is it possible to trigger scanning automatically on OS X?
All I was able to find is http://blog.scottkleper.com/scanline-command-line-scanner-for-mac/, which is rather good, only that it can scan into pdfs. I don't feel like adding support for jpegs myself.

Can I scan documents with either with a terminal command or applescript?

Comment: Not sure if this helps? [How do I automate clicking a button in an application's window with AppleScript?](http://superuser.com/questions/336551/how-do-i-automate-clicking-a-button-in-an-applications-window-with-applescript)

Comment: @slhck thanks, that would presumably work, but it's somewhat hacky solution. I'm kind of hoping for a better automation, one that would not interrupt users work. Will have to use this though if nothing else pops up.

Comment: maybe there's something to hide a window. like for windows there's hstart by ntwind, but maybe there is something for osx. or something in applescript that hides the window

Comment: [user285892](http://superuser.com/users/285892/user285892) - Are you still looking for a solution? I can add a -jpg option to scanline relatively easily if you still need it.

Comment: @CanadianLuke indeed I am. You will be most awesome if you actually implement it :) I looked at the repo and as a matter of fact I tried to implement jpeg output. I suppose it would be handled somewhere around https://github.com/klep/scanline/blob/master/scanline/AppController.m#L351 but then again I have no idea. Thank you :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have added a -jpeg / -jpg option to scanline. Note that the comment above was from me, but @CanadianLuke reposted it as a comment because it was "not an answer". Hopefully this is considered an answer -- here's a direct link to download the scanline binary with -jpg support:

http://scottkleper.com/scanline

Comment: Glad someone else finds it useful. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a Python based CLI for scanning documents on Mac.
You can find it here: https://github.com/zegman/scanner-cli

It provides a CLI interface which can be used to start a scan and capture it to a file in your folder of your choosing.

```
usage: scanner.py [-h] [--source {feeder,flatbed,automatic}] [--format {pdf,jpeg}]
                  [--grayscale] [--resolution {75,100,200,300,600}] [--debug] [--no-open]
                  [--quiet] [--duplex]
                  filename

positional arguments:
  filename

optional arguments:
  -h, --help            show this help message and exit
  --source {feeder,flatbed,automatic}, -S {feeder,flatbed,automatic}
  --format {pdf,jpeg}, -f {pdf,jpeg}
  --grayscale, -g
  --resolution {75,100,200,300,600}, -r {75,100,200,300,600}
  --debug, -d
  --no-open, -o
  --quiet, -q
  --duplex, -D
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1128810)

Comment: Confirm this script works for me